# What is the command to match brackets in Emacs?

Tags: linux, emacs, pattern-matching, editor, gnu

What is the command to match brackets in Emacs (the equivalent of the `%` command in Vim)?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

See `show-paren-mode` as described in [5.27 How do I show which parenthesis matches the one I'm looking at?](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/efaq.html#Matching-parentheses)

Comment: Also `C-M-u` and `C-M-d`. see *[Moving in the Parenthesis Structure](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Moving-by-Parens.html)*...

Answer (score 40):

`C-M-f`, or `M-x forward-sexp`, goes forward to the closing brace, or to the opening brace in the next set of braces. `C-M-b`, or `M-x backward-sexp`, goes backward to the opening brace, or to the closing brace in the next set of braces. These commands will work for parentheses, square brackets, curly braces, angle brackets, etc., and can be customized to recognize other delimiters.

Answer (score 10):

Just to complete the last response. I use `C-M-n` for forward match and `C-M-u` for backward match. `C-M` maps to <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on windows keyboards.

Comment: Strange combination of shortcuts, but I'm new to `emacs` and anyway here's [the useful related link](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Moving-by-Parens.html).

Answer (score 3):

There is also a `show-paren-mode`. For navigation, I think it's better `C-M-n` and `C-M-n`

Comment: Yes, but sometimes the matching paren isn't currently on the screen. This is when forward/backward-sexp really come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/redguardtoo/evil-matchit

I read vim matchit code before developing evil-matchit. evil-matchit is offering much more than original vim matchit now.

Besides, you can easily extend evil-matchit to support any new languages in your own ~/.emacs.

Comment: Cool!  It looks like this supports stuff like matching tags in XML also, including languages HTML Python Java C++/C Javascript, JSON Perl Latex CMake Org-mode Ruby Bash Lua PHP Laravel Blade Templating Vim script Emacs email (mesage-mode)