# Emacs Brace and Bracket Highlighting?

Tags: c++, c, linux, emacs, coding-style

When entering code Emacs transiently highlights the matching brace or bracket. With existing code however is there a way to ask it to highlight a matching brace or bracket if I highlight its twin?

I am often trying to do a sanity check when dealing with compiler errors and warnings. I do enter both braces usually when coding before inserting the code in between, but have on occasion unintentionally commented out one brace when commenting out code while debugging.

Any advice with dealing with brace and bracket matching with Emacs?

OS is mostly Linux/Unix, but I do use it also on OS X and Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the command to match brackets in Emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261522/what-is-the-command-to-match-brackets-in-emacs)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're dealing with a language that supports it, give [ParEdit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) a serious look. If you're not using with a Lisp dialect, it's not nearly as useful though.

For general brace/bracket/paren highlighting, look into [highlight-parentheses](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightParentheses) mode (which color codes multiple levels of braces whenever `point` is inside them). You can also turn on `show-paren-mode` through customizations (that is `M-x customize-variable show-paren-mode`); that one strongly highlights the brace/bracket/paren matching one at point (if the one at point doesn't match anything, you get a different color).

my `.emacs` currently contains (among other things)

```lisp
(require 'highlight-parentheses)

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-highlight-parentheses-mode highlight-parentheses-mode
  (lambda nil (highlight-parentheses-mode t)))

(global-highlight-parentheses-mode t)
```

as well as that `show-paren-mode` customization, which serves me well (of course, I also use paredit when lisping, but these are still marginally useful).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the answer straight from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Matching.html) or [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowParenMode), also have a look at [autopair](http://code.google.com/p/autopair/).

Answer (score 2):

tried on emacs 26

```
(show-paren-mode 1)
(setq show-paren-style 'mixed)
```

- enable showing parentheses
- set the showing in such as highlit the braces char., or if either one invisible higlight what they enclose

for toggling the cursor position / point between both, put this script in .emacs

```
(defun swcbrace ()(interactive)
  (if (looking-at "(")(forward-list)
  (backward-char)
  (cond
    ((looking-at ")")(forward-char)(backward-list))
    ((looking-at ".)")(forward-char 2)(backward-list))
  )))
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-next>") 'swcbrace)
```

it works toggling by press Control-Pgdn

Answer (score 1):

BTW, for the immediate question: M-x blink-matching-open will "re-blink" for an existing close paren, as if you had just inserted it.  Another way to see the matching paren is to use M-C-b and M-C-f (which jump over matched pairs of parens), which are also very useful navigation commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the below in your `init.el`:

```
(setq show-paren-delay 0)
(show-paren-mode 1)
```

to ensure matching parenthesis are highlighted.

Note that `(setq show-paren-delay 0)` needs to be set before `(show-paren-mode 1)` so that there's no delay in highlighting, as per the [wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowParenMode).

If you want to do a quick check to see whether brackets in the current file are balanced:
`M-x check-parens`

Both options tested on Emacs 27.1

Answer (score 0):

I second ParEdit. it is very good atleast for lisp development.

FWIW I use this function often to go to matching paren (back and forth).

```lisp
;; goto-matching-paren
;; -------------------
;; If point is sitting on a parenthetic character, jump to its match.
;; This matches the standard parenthesis highlighting for determining which
;; one it is sitting on.
;;
(defun goto-matching-paren ()
  "If point is sitting on a parenthetic character, jump to its match."
  (interactive)
  (cond ((looking-at "\\s\(") (forward-list 1))
        ((progn
           (backward-char 1)
           (looking-at "\\s\)")) (forward-char 1) (backward-list 1))))
(define-key global-map [(control ?c) ?p] 'goto-matching-paren) ; Bind to C-c p
```

Declaimer: I am NOT the author of this function, copied from internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check the balanced delimiters, be them parentheses, square brackets or curly braces, you can use `backward-sexp` (bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) and `forward-sexp` (bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>) to skip backward and forward to the corresponding delimiter. These commands are very handy to navigate through source files, skipping structures and function definitions, without any buffer modifications.