# How to customize emacs in python-mode to highlight corresponding bracket for a half-second?

Tags: emacs

How to customize emacs in python-mode to highlight corresponding bracket for a half-second when you put cursor on bracket?

For example, as it done in Qt Creator.

Ideally, I would like to work this in Python, C++ and Java modes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/261522/1225607

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting makes bracket highlight. but not for half a second

```
(show-paren-mode 1)
```