# emacs: highlight all code within matching parenthesis off screen

Tags: emacs

I have the following two lines in my emacs config file which work perfectly for me:

```
(show-paren-mode 1);;highlight matching paranthesis
(setq show-paren-style 'expression) ; highlight entire bracket expression
```

except..when the function is too large to be displayed on one screen. When I scroll down to see the matching close braces ,  it stops highlighting as soon as the open braces goes offscreen. 
How do I get emacs to highlight expressions within a set of matching braces even if I scroll down , as long as my cursor is on a braces?

Comment: I do not have a solution for `show-parens-mode`.  If you would like to use a different library such as `highlight-parentheses`, then the following link contains a modification of said library to permit scrolling without deleting the overlays that show matching parentheses:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25269210/2112489

Comment: Set `blink-matching-paren` to non-`nil`. Turn on `blink-cursor-mode`. This tells you what a right paren matches when you insert it. The general problem with showing a matching left paren is how far back to go, to look for it. That's what option `blink-matching-paren-distance` is for.